# Code editing using bash script and test processing

Tags: c++, linux, bash, unix, awk

I have a file that defines many methods with headers of the form

```
void Method1(double arg1[M][N], double arg2[M][N], ...)
{
}
```

I would like to use a bash script to replace the arguments `"double arg1[M][N]"` and `"double arg2[M][N]"` with `"const vector<vector<double>>& arg1"` and `"vector<vector<double>>& arg2"`, respectively, so that the 
function header reads as

```
void Method1(const vector<vector<double>>& arg1, const vector<vector<double>>& arg2, ...)
{
}
```

How can I implement this using awk or sed? So far I have tried calling `sed` twice on the file like this

```
sed -i "s/double/const vector\<vector\<double\>\>\&/g" file.cpp
```

followed by

```
sed -i "s/\[M\]\[N\]//g" file.cpp
```

but the first call to sed matches anything with the pattern "double" in it, including methods with only scalar arguments of type `double`, which must remain untouched.

Comment: Fazlin -- you had a good approach, just `sed 's/double \(arg[0-9]\)\[M\]\[N\]/const vector<vector<double>>\& \1/g'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short version (well not that short) using `sed` with basic-regular-expressions could look something like:

```
sed -i 's/double arg1\[M\]\[N\],[ ]double arg2\[M\]\[N\]/const vector<vector<double>>\& arg1, const vector<vector<double>>\& arg2/' yourfiles
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ echo "void Method1(double arg1[M][N], double arg2[M][N], ...)" | 
sed 's/double arg1\[M\]\[N\],[ ]double arg2\[M\]\[N\]/const vector<vector<double>>\& arg1, const vector<vector<double>>\& arg2/'
void Method1(const vector<vector<double>>& arg1, const vector<vector<double>>& arg2, ...)
```

You can add the additional guard of `0,/double arg1\[M\]\[N\],[ ]double arg2\[M\]\[N\]/` before the `s/.../.../` to ensure only the 1st occurrence in the file is replaced if you need to limit to 1 replacement.

**Edit to Add Capture Groups and Backreferences**

Per your comment, if the array names need to be generalized, you can match and capture the name with `\([^[]*\)` and reinsert the name using a numbered backreference (`\1` and `\2`), e.g.

```
sed 's/double \([^[]*\)\[M\]\[N\],[ ]double \([^[]*\)\[M\]\[N\]/const vector<vector<double>>\& \1, const vector<vector<double>>\& \2/'
```

**Edit Per-Request for `awk` Solution**

As mentioned in the comment, this problem does not really lend itself to an `awk` solution for two reasons (1) the function declaration isn't a delimited set of fields that are easily broken on a *field-separator*; and (2) `awk` does not provide for *in-place* replacement within a file. (some versions do, otherwise you have to use write to a new file and replace the old)

To use `awk` for this problem, you basically have to systematically apply the string-manipulation functions to substitute the needed substrings. Doable, just not what you would consider a normal first-choice approach. You can do it similar to:

```
# match line with "... arg1[M][N], double arg2[M][N]"
awk -F", " '/[^[]*\[M\]\[N\],[ ][^[]*\[M\]\[N\]/ {
    gsub(/double/,"const vector<vector<double>>&")  # sub double/<vector<vector<double>>&
    gsub(/\[M\]\[N\]/,"")                           # remove [M][N]
}1' files                                           # print record
```

The command above simply substitutes `double` for the *reference to vector of vector of doubles* syntax using `gsub` to operate on the entire record. Then uses `gsub` again to remove the `"[M][N]"` leaving the record in the form desired. There are many ways to do this is just the <s>first</s> second way that came to mind with `awk`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Your solution works perfectly for the given method signature. However, the argument names "arg1" and "arg2" were used only as examples; there are several of these methods defined in the file with different argument names. Is there a more generic way of matching `double blah[M][N]`?

Comment: Yes, you can use `double \([^[]*])\[M\]\[N\],` as the *match* with the capture group `\(...\)` preserving the name for each, but then you will need to re-insert the backreference. I'll drop an edit.

Comment: OK, it works! I mean, your generic version with capture groups and back references: `sed -i 's/double \([^[]*\)\[M\]\[N\]/const vector<vector<double>>\& \1/g' file.cpp` This is highly appreciated as it will save me long hours of manually editing the functions across several files.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer but how can it also be implemented using awk?

Comment: @unbound37 question is, why would you like to implement this in awk ? - looks like a job for sed

Comment: @CorentinLimier No particular reason other than to compare both options and see which is faster?

Comment: @unbound37 I'll look at an `awk` solution, but this is actually better using `sed` to take the line as stream rather than trying to parse it as `"fields"`. May work out, but will be messier.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could try below `sed`:

```
sed 's/double \(arg[0-9]\)\(\[[MN]\]\[[MN]\]\)/const vector\<vector\<double\>\>\& \1/g' file.cpp
```

The above command searches for pattern `arg[0-9]` between `double` and `[M][N]` and places that between your required `const vector` pattern. This can work with any number of arguments.

I have not included `-i` option of `sed` so that you can verify before updating.

Comment: I'll vote for that one too. Good use of the global. Note, you don't' have to escape `<` or `>` in the *replace* field. (see comment under original question)

Comment: Only downside would be if a function contained only one array (or more than two arrays) as parameters, you may trigger some stray replacements.